# Air con. When zone 1 is selected different zones blow also

Tags: air-conditioning

I have 6 zones on My aircon. When I select zone 1. Air blows through several zones. When I select zone 3 that zone doesn't blow any air, but other zones start blowing out air. Currently only half of the rooms work. Any ideas. I've turned the aircon unit off at the fuse board and by the power switch by the aircon unit. No luck

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. When did this start happening? What make/model is your system?

Comment: Sounds like there are probably malfunctioning (or disconnected wires to) zone dampers, some stuck open, some stuck closed.

Comment: Possible wires disconnected but In my experience the systems need cleaning because of multiple different failures The actuators need TLC and rarely ever get until they fail.